# Odd behavior when trying to extract the value of one variable at the point where another is maximized `m1[, apply(m2, 1, which.max)]`

Tags: r, subscript

I'm trying to efficiently and succinctly calculate the value of one variable at the point where another is maximized, and I don't understand R's behavior when I try to do it in (what seems like) the most straightforward way:

```
> set.seed(1)
> m1 <- matrix(round(runif(16,1,10),2),4)
> m2 <- matrix(round(runif(16,1,10),2),4)  
> m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 3.39 2.82 6.66 7.18
[2,] 4.35 9.09 1.56 4.46
[3,] 6.16 9.50 2.85 7.93
[4,] 9.17 6.95 2.59 5.48
> m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 7.46 9.41 3.40 8.83
[2,] 9.93 2.91 4.48 4.06
[3,] 4.42 6.87 1.12 5.34
[4,] 8.00 2.13 4.44 6.40
> m1[, as.numeric(apply(m2, 1, which.max))]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 2.82 3.39 2.82 3.39
[2,] 9.09 4.35 9.09 4.35
[3,] 9.50 6.16 9.50 6.16
[4,] 6.95 9.17 6.95 9.17
```

1. What is going on here?  The vector that I'm subscripting with has length 4.  Why am I getting the matrix?
2. How can I get what I'm looking for?  Should be a vector of `2.82, 4.35, 9.5, 9.17` in this example.

Comment: Try `m1[cbind(1:4,apply(m2, 1, which.max))]`. I'm not sure exactly why you're surprised by the results. `m1[,c(2,1,2,1)]` is pretty basic syntax for selecting the 2nd, the 1st, the 2nd and then the 1st column.

Comment: Ah that explains it.  I was getting the whole column.  Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `m1[cbind(1:nrow(m1), max.col(m2, "first"))]`